# search on huge sqlite database on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary, cursor

**hi

i have a database with 500,000 Record .

want to search in database like on dictionary search for searching word .

i use this query :**

```
SELECT id,word FROM dic WHERE word like 'test%' LIMIT 10
```

**but is'ts slowly searching, i index word field and field are ASC order in database

no way to searching in huge database ?

example :**
**when entered text is "Hel" i get who word is starting with "Hel" in database.

database create sql code :**

```
CREATE TABLE [dic] (
[id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[word] TEXT(100)  NOT NULL,
[mean] TEXT(1000000)  NULL,
[pron] TEXT(1000)  NULL,
[form] TEXT(1000)  NULL
);
CREATE INDEX [table_index] ON [dic](
[word]  ASC
);
```

Comment: btw: 500K rows is not huge. Not even close... You haven't shown schema, queries , or what indexes you have created.

Comment: 500,000 is Huge for Mobile System !

Answer (score 3):

`LIKE` queries usually don't use an index, so sqlite is performing a table scan. However, you can convince sqlite into using an index by making it a range condition, like so:

```
SELECT id, word 
  FROM dic 
 WHERE word BETWEEN 'test' AND 'test{'
 LIMIT 10
```

Note that "test" < "testa" and "{" > "z"

Comment: Making sure I understand: you're suggesting `{` because its character code is above any alphanumeric values we'd expect to see?

Comment: Correct; clarified that in the response. "test" will always be less than test + any character, and { follows z.

Answer (score 0):

try to use glob instead of like, i found it much faster in some cases

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, operator `LIKE` is case-insensitive by default, and this is the reason why `LIKE 'test%'` does not use an index. If you add `NOCASE` clause to your index creation statement:

```
CREATE INDEX dic_word_idx ON dic (word COLLATE NOCASE);
```

then `LIKE 'test%'` will start using this index. But, then you have to use consistent case when storing and comparing your words - for example, always store lower-case, and always fold to lower-case before searching.

In addition to that, you should change your database schema. Currently, your table has very wide row - as big as 1 MB.

Instead, split it into two tables: one relatively small table containing only word, and another slave table containing full article. I would expect that your words table will be less than 1% of original table, and thus will be much faster to read even if full scan is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The [`GLOB` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) is case sensitive, so if you use `GLOB 'test*'` instead of `LIKE 'test%'`, SQLite will be able to use your index.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option of creating full-text searchable tables using SQLite FTS extensions, see [here: Storing and Searching for Data](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html)